# Failed to list version for package

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

After migrating to version 3 of gradle, I get this error in all packages

```
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/chrisbanes/PhotoView/2.0.0/PhotoView-2.0.0.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/chrisbanes/PhotoView/2.0.0/PhotoView-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/frankiesardo/icepick/3.2.0/icepick-3.2.0.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/frankiesardo/icepick/3.2.0/icepick-3.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages/v0.1/ClickableAreasImages-v0.1.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages/v0.1/ClickableAreasImages-v0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/chrisbanes/PhotoView/2.0.0/PhotoView-2.0.0.pom'.
Error:org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not HEAD 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/chrisbanes/PhotoView/2.0.0/PhotoView-2.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Error:org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/frankiesardo/icepick/3.2.0/icepick-3.2.0.pom'.
```

Error:
[image: error]

Comment: Unless you share repository configuration information, the only possible answer is: you no longer have access to that s3 bucket.